# Error with const string member : no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, constructor

I am getting `no appropriate default constructor available` error with the following simple piece of code:

```
    class A
{
    public:
        const string cs ;

};

void main()
{
    A a;
    return;
}
```

If I remove the `const` from string then code compiles fine. I can not understand why the `default constructor` is not getting created by compiler? And what is the deal with `const string` member variable?
I am working on VS2008.

Comment: `const` variables have to be initialized. And `void main` is not C++. Use `int main`.

Comment: This might sound like a stupid question, but did you `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @BrianBi Judging by this: "If I remove the "const" from string then code compiles fine." I'm going with yes, he has that covered.

Comment: @chris, there's nothing wrong with declaring a `const` variable like that. It just uses the default constructor.

Comment: you are required to initialise const variable in c++

Comment: @BrianBi, Oops, I didn't see it was actually a string, not a built in type, thanks. Still seems a bit odd to have a constant empty string.

Comment: @chris, indeed it does

Comment: @chris If I give and empty default ctor for class A, which doesnot initialize the "const string" member, then also it compiles fine. So, it has nothing to do with const initialization I think.

Comment: And if the empty default ctor works then why compiler generated default ctor is not working in this case?

Comment: @Anitesh seems nothing wrong. Is this all your code?

Comment: @Anitesh, Yes, it works because the string is default-initialized. Anyway, it should work with the compiler-given ctor. It's most likely a bug in VS2008.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you provide a default constructor for `A` *and* specify `cs()` in an initializer list? You mentioned it isn't a problem if there is np initializer list with a specific `A::A()`. What happens if there *is* ?

Comment: `void main()` ??

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `const` variables cannot be left unitialized in C++. There are two ways you can initialize your variable. In both cases, the content of the string can never be modified (as this is what `const` means).

1) In the class declaration. This method is useful only if you always want this string to have the same value across all of your objects. It is very inflexible and if you find yourself using it you should probably declare the variable as `static`.

```
class A
{
    const string cs = "value of cs";
};
```

2) assign it in the constructor, using constructor chaining. This is much more flexible and idiomatic.

```
class A
{
     const string cs;

 public:

     A() : cs("value of cs") 
     {

     }

 };
```

Note that this can be used with arguments, eg

```
A(string s) : cs(s) //initializes cs to the value of s
```

Your error probably arises from the compiler trying to find the second option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned in one of the comments above that  If I give and empty default ctor for class A, which does not have initialization list to initialize const string, then also it compiles fine. And if the empty default ctor works then why compiler generated default ctor is not working in this case?

Comment: This isn't true for everything. If the type provides no default construction, then it is true, otherwise [**See It Live**](http://ideone.com/k3uRi6). There is no reason if presented as shown that the OP's code should experience this issue. The class `std::string` has a default constructor. The result is a rather pointless empty string in the OP's case, but there isn't anything wrong with that besides sanity.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for the link "See it Live". I think it was a bug which C++ 11.0 has overcame. I can see it is not showing compilation error in C++ 11.0.

Comment: @WhozCraig I assumed that the problem was with `A`'s default constructor, not `std::string`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++17 it is legal to have a `const` member with no initializer -- if that member has a default constructor which initializes itself.   `void main()` is still incorrect though!

So here is some valid code:

```
#include <string>

struct A { const std::string cs; };

int main()
{
     A a;
}
```

The string `a.cs` is an empty string which is `const`.

If using an older compiler you will have to give a redundant initializer for `cs`.